# Clear multi select list using jQuery without resizing it

Tags: jquery, select

Here's my code:

```
   var select = $('#subjectslist');
   select.each(function(index, option) 
    {
        $(option).remove();
    });
   $.each(subjects, function(key, subject) 
   {
       if (select.find('option[value="' + subject + '"]').length === 0 && subject!="") 
   {
     //Ajouter la nouvelle catégorie dans la liste
      $('<option>', {
       value: subject,
       text: subject
       }).appendTo(select);
  }
```

});

Here's my problem:

My multi select disappears completely because of the first **each** loop. 
How can I just make it empty the multi select before filling it again without resizing it?

Comment: Do you mean resizing in terms of width?  If so, you need to set a width with CSS.  Otherwise, the width is automatically set based on options and available width.

Comment: Hm, you're right, but it's just secondary for the moment. My real problem is that with this code, the second loop won't work when the first one is uncommented. My multi select disappears completely.

Comment: while your variable is called `option` your loop is looping over the `select`.  What you really want is `var options = $('#selectslist option')` or `select.find('option').each(function(index, option)`

Comment: Worked with `$('#subjectslist').children().remove()` instead of first loop. :)

Comment: I would say try .empty() or .detach instead of .remove() as in $(option).empty(); this will keep the select box from vanishing

Comment: I promoted my comment to an answer.  Please mark it as the answer you chose in order to help future searchers.

Comment: of course you need width as well as Eli stated

Answer (score 1):

While your variable is called `option` in your loop, your loop is actually looping over the `select` element (only one since found by id) and then removing itself from the DOM.

What you really want is var options = `$('#subjectslist option')` or `select.find('option').each(function(index, option)` or `select.children().remove();` or some preferred version therein.